# "Drop by" or "Drop in"

Tags: word-choice, difference

> Do you know the cafe down the street? I always go there after work. You should drop by/in someday.

Can both "by" and "in" be used here? Is there a difference between them? Which one is more natural?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, both are colloquial and may be used in this context.

However, **drop in** implies entering a building while **drop by** is neutral in this respect and may be used in other contexts - to see an allotment, admire a new car, watch a sports match.